# API Gateway with SAM isn't updated correctly

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

We use Cloud Formation for define a bunch of Lambda functions:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform:
- 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'

Resources:
  MyLambda:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: com.handler::MyLambda
      Runtime: java8
      CodeUri: .
      Description: Some desc
      MemorySize: 512
      Timeout: 15
      Role: !Ref LambdaRole
      FunctionName: MyLambda
      Events:
        MyLambdaEvt:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref MyApiDef
            Path: /lambda/my
            Method: get

  MyApiDef:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      DefinitionUri: s3://a-bucket/api-gateway.yml
      StageName: prod

Outputs:
  ApiUrl:
    Description: URL of your API endpoint
    Value: !Join
      - ''
      - - https://
        - !Ref MyApiDef
        - '.execute-api.'
        - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
        - '.amazonaws.com/prod'
```

A CodePipeline generate a changeset and execute it.

In this way all the Lambda function are correctly updated but the API Gateway endpoint are not update correctly and we need to import and deploy the YML in `s3://a-bucket/api-gateway.yml` manually.

Comment: Any errors during stack creation/updation? And what do you mean by 'API Gateway endpoint are not update correctly'?

Comment: No error during stack creation/updating. Lambda functions (defined in CloudFormation) are updated, API endpoint (defined in the Swagger with API Gateway extensions) are not updated at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why the API doesn't update (an educated guess)**

In order for a change to be added to a a [change set](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-changesets.html), CloudFormation has to detect a change.  If the only thing that changes (for `MyApiDef`) between deployments is the contents of the .yaml file out on S3, CloudFormation isn't going to detect a change that it needs to add to the change set.

If this API definition lived in the CF template, rather than a file on S3, CF would (obviously) detect every change and update the API for you.

Since the definition lives in S3, and the file name hasn't changed, no change is detected, so nothing gets updated.

**Possible work arounds**

You have to convince CloudFormation that something has changed with your API definition.  These two things worked for me:

- Updating the `MyApiDef` key itself each run works. (`MyApiDefv2`,
  `MyApiDefv3`, etc)
- Updating the `DefinitionUri` works. (i.e. version the
  filename in S3).

Neither of these is great, but appending a version to the filename in S3 seems more reasonable than the other option.

There are probably other ways to convince CloudFormation a change has taken place.  Notably, I could *not* get [`Variables`](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessapi) to work for this purpose.

Comment: I cannot verify right now, but the educated guess seems pretty reasonable, maybe I will switch from `DefinitionUri` to `DefinitionBody`, dynamically adding the body during the CodeBuild phase (in this way CloudFormation definitions file will not bloat)... Hope that it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on Mike Patrick's explanation, I found another workaround. Instead of changing the names or versioning your files, simply run a deployment of your API Gateway right after `sam deploy`is completed. Check out these steps:

1. Add a reference to your apigateway on the outputs of your SAM template:

```yaml
Outputs:
  MyApiId:
    Value: !Ref MyApiDef
```

2. Run these commands after `sam deploy` (you need aws-cli installed):

```bash
export GATEWAY_ID=$(aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name <the_name_of_your_stack> --query 'Stacks[0].Outputs[?OutputKey==`MyApiId`].OutputValue' --output text)
aws apigateway create-deployment --rest-api-id $GATEWAY_ID --stage-name <your_state_name>
```

Voilá!